# Уничтожение обьекта после соприкосновения с полом

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть падающие обьекты, которые регенерируются постоянно в рандом позиции, через `Random.Range`. Обьект у меня типа `GameObject`, добавил метод `OnCollisionEnter2D`, в котором указал, что если тег "other" геймобджекта равняется "floor", то у меня должен уничтожатся обьект. Вместо этого мне выдаёт ошибку:

`Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss. If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);`

На сколько я понял, я удаляю именно этот обьект, можно как нибудь пофиксить?

Сразу скажу, программирование я пока что только учу, так что если что то очевидное, не бейте пожалуйста :>

Код:

```cs
public GameObject Spike;
public float fspeed;
private float timeSpawn = 45f;
    
public Rigidbody2D rb;
public GameObject player;
public float speed;
public float jforce;

void Start () {
    rb.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Floor")
        Destroy (Spike);
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "FallSp") {
        Destroy (player);
        SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
    }
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    float RandPos = Random.Range (9.87f, -9.87f);
    timeSpawn = timeSpawn + 1f;
    if (timeSpawn == 45f)
        Instantiate (Spike, new Vector2 (RandPos, 7.96f), Quaternion.identity);
    if (timeSpawn > 45f)
        timeSpawn = timeSpawn = 1f;
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        rb.AddForce (Vector2.up * jforce * Time.deltaTime);
    float xPos = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    player.transform.Translate (new Vector2 (xPos, 0f) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

IEnumerator Iek() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds (1f);
}
```

[image: Код]

Comment: Покажите код, в пятницу вечером с воображением неочень.

Comment: Не скришот, а код.

Comment: И нет, ты не понял. Ты пытаешься удалить не объект, а его префаб (asset), что довольно однозначно говорится в тексте ошибки.

Comment: А можно это как нибудь исправить?

Comment: Вам стоит изучить, как [создать минимальный пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) и [задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
Это очень важно сделать, если вы хотите успешно пользоваться сайтами Stack Exchange в будущем

Comment: Совет от меня: переводите и вчитывайтесь в ошибки, после чего смотрите, почему они могли возникнуть

Comment: Хорошо, извините если туплю, я подобными форумами никогда не пользовался, и много чего не знаю.

Comment: Так работает с каждым префабом или только с одним? Если с одним, то убери его со сцены и добавь копию. Но а вообще в коде все нормально, за исключением что не видно спавна спайка твоего. Но я предполагаю что ты в сцене расставлял

Comment: У меня его не было на сцене) Я его сначала кинул на сцену для установки коллайдера и риджидбади, потом перекинул в папочку с префабами, указав тег. Сам обьект я удалил, и в инспекторе указал префаб спайка.

Answer (score 1):

Вы удаляете префаб в ассетах а не обьект

Comment: А как обьект удалить?